# Java Simple Date format Conversion

Tags: java

If `2011-11-26T03:53:00.001-0800` is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Then what is `2011-11-26T03:53:00.001-08:00`

Hope it explains everything what i need...

Comment: *Hope it explains everything what i need...* No it doesn't. What is the question here?

Comment: if the date format of 2011-11-26T03:53:00.001-0800 is yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ, then what is the date format of 2011-11-26T03:53:00.001-08:00, Please note the difference between the two... -0800 and -08:00

Comment: Yes, it doesnt explain what you want. Please elaborate.

Comment: What do you want it for?

Comment: Ok.. When im parsing an Atom feed im getting the date as <published>2011-11-26T03:53:00.001-08:00</published> and i want to parse it in Java using SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"); So i need the date format..

Comment: @AmithGC: can you edit the date (that you are getting from the feed) a little bit? Like remove the `:` or add something in the date string?

Comment: *"Hope it explains everything what i need..."*  From the description it seems you need a personal man-servant.  [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i've found a solution to your problem.

"*The solution is possibly to use the data type converter in JAXB, since JAXB must be able to parse ISO8601 date string according to the XML Schema specification.* `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("1999-01-01T23:59:59.999-08:00")` *will give you a Calendar object and you can simply use `getTime()` on it, if you need a Date object.*"

[This is the link where i found the above answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date?answertab=votes#tab-top)

You can simply use it like this:

```
Calendar cl = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("1999-01-01T23:59:59.999-08:00");
System.out.println(cl.getTime());
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Hmmm.. it works.. this is the way it has to be done.... :) will read more... thanks....

Answer (score 1):

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz
```

From RFC822 Timezone to General timezone. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone)

Comment: Abhinav, i have read it before.. sadly, it has nothing which explains my problem...

Comment: @AmithGC: note he used a lowercase "Z", not the uppercase "Z" you used.

Comment: @abhinav: please excuse the edit, I changed it to point to the format specifier of interest (i.e. the "timezone" specifier).

Comment: For this format to work your date string should be something like this `1999-01-01T23:59:59.999GMT-01:00`.